# Is it okay to have reduplicated names or same first and last name?

Tags: names

Is it okay to have reduplicated names or same first name and last name?
for example Daniel Danielson.

Comment: http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/NIA.html I thought we had this question already

Comment: [כָּל מִי שֶׁנִּכְפַּל שְׁמוֹ יֵשׁ לוֹ בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה וְיֵשׁ לוֹ בָּעוֹלָם הַבָּא](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.30?lang=bi)

Comment: Avner ben Ner? 
@DoubleAA, Abraham S. Abraham, אתיא אס ופסיק.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see now that you are asking about the secular family name. Since this is not really the name of the person, it would not matter. One should not give the child the same name as his father (such as Reuven ben Reuven) unless the father has died before the child's bris milah. Ashkenaz custom has extended this to not name a child after any living relative.

For example [Abraham Abraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Abraham) was the son of Judah Abraham. Thus his real (Jewish) name was Avraham ben Yehudah.

Comment: Admittedly, It would simplify my remembering a person's name when calling him for an *aliyah*. I'd love to have someone named *Levi ben Levi Halevi*

Comment: @DanF I know a Levi HaLevi Levy (and have met a Shalom Shalem, an Isaac Isaacs, an Isaac Ishakis, a Dovid Davidi, and a Shlomo Solomon). I kid you not.